# How to work with quarternions in Wolfram Mathematica?

Tags: quaternions

How can I write the insructions from this link http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2011/08/25/quaternion-properties-and-interactive-rotations-with-wolframalpha/ in Mathematica to obtain the same result?

Thanks!

Comment: You might have a look here: [link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/FromQuaternionTo3DRotation/)

Comment: To comply with StackExchange policy, please make the question *self-contained*.  Do not just post a link, explain clearly what you need.

Comment: WolframAlpha["quaternion: 2-i+j+3k"]

WolframAlpha["quaternions: 2-i+j+3k multiplied by 2-i+j+0k multiplied by 1-i+j+k"]

Answer (score 6):

To do the calculation without recourse to Wolfram|Alpha you can do

```
Needs["Quaternions`"]
Quaternion[2, 1, 1, 3] ** Quaternion[2, 1, 1, 0] ** Quaternion[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

> ```
> Quaternion[-12, 4, 14, 2]
> ```

Or you can do this

[image: quaternions]